# WSO2 IS MFA with Open Ldap issues

Tags: wso2, openldap, wso2-identity-server

I have Identity Server 5.1.0 in which I configured Open Ldap through Read-Write model in user-mgt.xml. Now I am trying to add Multiple factor authentication(MFA) through this link,
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ISCONNECTORS/Configuring+TOTP+Authenticator

I am getting errors when I click Scan QR.

```
 TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-10 12:18:42,459]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  'sid@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2016-06-10 12:18:42,458+0530] 
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-10 12:19:27,601]  INFO {JAGGERY.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.my-profile.totp-init:jag} -  Calling the web service .... url https://localhost:9443/services/TOTPAdminService 
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-10 12:19:27,666] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.totp.services.TOTPAdminService} -  TOTPAdminService failed to generateTOTP key for the user : sid@carbon.super 
org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.totp.exception.TOTPException: TOTPKeyGenerator failed while trying to access userRealm for the user : sid
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.totp.TOTPKeyGenerator.getQRCodeURL(TOTPKeyGenerator.java:142)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.totp.services.TOTPAdminService.initTOTP(TOTPAdminService.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:173)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:146)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.CarbonServlet.doPost(CarbonServlet.java:231)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Profile information could not be updated in LDAP user store for user : sid
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.handleException(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:2074)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.doSetUserClaimValue(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:1013)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.setUserClaimValue(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:1151)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.totp.TOTPKeyGenerator.getQRCodeURL(TOTPKeyGenerator.java:139)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: javax.naming.InvalidNameException: cn=sid: [LDAP: error code 64 - value of naming attribute 'cn' is not present in entry]; remaining name 'cn=sid'
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3025)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2840)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_modifyAttributes(LdapCtx.java:1411)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_modifyAttributes(ComponentDirContext.java:253)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.modifyAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:165)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.modifyAttributes(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:154)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.doSetUserClaimValue(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:1009)
    ... 59 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-10 12:19:27,692] ERROR {JAGGERY.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.my-profile.totp-init:jag} -  org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: TOTPAdminService failed to generateTOTP key for the user : sid@carbon.super (/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/wsUtil.jag#27)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.c0._c_call_1(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/wsUtil.jag:27)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.c0.call(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/wsUtil.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.c0._c_callWSReturnXML_4(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/wsUtil.jag:87)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.c0.call(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/wsUtil.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.c0._c_callWSReturnJSON_5(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/wsUtil.jag:102)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.c0.call(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/wsUtil.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.my_profile.c2._c_init_1(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/my-profile/totp-init.jag:21)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.my_profile.c2.call(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/my-profile/totp-init.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName0(OptRuntime.java:74)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.my_profile.c2._c_script_0(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/my-profile/totp-init.jag:30)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.my_profile.c2.call(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/my-profile/totp-init.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.my_profile.c2.call(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/my-profile/totp-init.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.my_profile.c2.exec(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/my-profile/totp-init.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:587)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:507)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: TOTPAdminService failed to generateTOTP key for the user : sid@carbon.super
    at org.jaggeryjs.modules.ws.WSRequestHostObject.jsFunction_send(WSRequestHostObject.java:404)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: TOTPAdminService failed to generateTOTP key for the user : sid@carbon.super
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:370)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:445)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:554)
    at org.jaggeryjs.modules.ws.WSRequestHostObject.jsFunction_send(WSRequestHostObject.java:379)
    ... 64 more

TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-10 12:19:27,695] ERROR {JAGGERY.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.my-profile.totp-init:jag} -  org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: TOTPAdminService failed to generateTOTP key for the user : sid@carbon.super (/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/wsUtil.jag#27)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.c0._c_call_1(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/wsUtil.jag:27)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.c0.call(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/wsUtil.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.c0._c_callWSReturnXML_4(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/wsUtil.jag:87)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.c0.call(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/wsUtil.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.c0._c_callWSReturnJSON_5(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/wsUtil.jag:102)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.c0.call(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/wsUtil.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.my_profile.c2._c_init_1(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/my-profile/totp-init.jag:21)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.my_profile.c2.call(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/my-profile/totp-init.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName0(OptRuntime.java:74)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.my_profile.c2._c_script_0(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/my-profile/totp-init.jag:30)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.my_profile.c2.call(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/my-profile/totp-init.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.my_profile.c2.call(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/my-profile/totp-init.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.my_profile.c2.exec(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/my-profile/totp-init.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:587)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:507)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: TOTPAdminService failed to generateTOTP key for the user : sid@carbon.super
    at org.jaggeryjs.modules.ws.WSRequestHostObject.jsFunction_send(WSRequestHostObject.java:404)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: TOTPAdminService failed to generateTOTP key for the user : sid@carbon.super
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:370)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:445)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:554)
    at org.jaggeryjs.modules.ws.WSRequestHostObject.jsFunction_send(WSRequestHostObject.java:379)
    ... 64 more

TID: [-1234] [] [2016-06-10 12:19:27,707] ERROR {JAGGERY.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.wsUtil:jag} -  org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.NullPointerException (/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/my-profile/profileClient.jag#26)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.my_profile.c0._c_getUserProfile_3(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/my-profile/profileClient.jag:26)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.controllers.my_profile.c0.call(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/controllers/my-profile/profileClient.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.c1._c_getUser_1(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/index.jag:14)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.c1.call(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/index.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName0(OptRuntime.java:74)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.c1._c_script_0(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/index.jag:5)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.c1.call(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/index.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.c1.call(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/index.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.portal.gadgets.user_profile.c1.exec(/portal/gadgets/user_profile/index.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:587)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:507)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.utils.multitenancy.MultitenantUtils.getTenantAwareUsername(MultitenantUtils.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    ... 53 more
```

May be user claims Settings need to change. Kindly help me

This is how my Ldap looks, http://prntscr.com/belb7i
Ldap connections is, cn=manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com & passsword is secret

Check my user store config here, http://pastebin.com/TtE7nJcq

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: javax.naming.InvalidNameException: cn=sid: [LDAP: error code 64 - value of naming attribute 'cn' is not present in entry]; remaining name 'cn=sid'

seems like wrong configuration of the userstore, Could you post the userstore config XML (without password) ? As well make sure the "cn=sid" really has properly uid and cn filled (I believe OpenLDAP uses uid by default)

> Profile information could not be updated in LDAP user store for user : sid

could you make sure that

- (cn=manager) has write access to the LDAP database
- on the installation page there are some claims configured. Can you make sure, that the object type (inetOrgPerson) has the configured claim attributes available? (stateOrProvinceName, nickname, location, ...)

Comment: I am new to Open Ldap and Wso2, I have set it up using this link, http://kukusan-network.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-setting-ldap-openldap-in-windows.html . I have simply added sid profile to existing data.
I do not know about claims configurations. I am trying to change them using, http://xacmlinfo.org/2012/05/02/claim-management-with-wso2-identity-server/

Comment: I don't think changing them will help. The TOTP simply needs to store its data along the user record and I pointed out where you should look. Unfortunately you have to handle yourself to make sure the connection user has proper rights or the data type has required attributes :/